# Cycles rendering dim lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes, light, lighting

This has been going on for a while now but I just want to fix this.

I have a nice bright scene in the viewport, but then when I render it, it looks way too dark.

Here is the .blend https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a7bX40YrLo2u1lplQ9KYhogwmmlm3XqG

[image: looks nice[1]]
[image: bad]

Comment: Please provide your .blend file with textures files packed inside. It will be faster for us to dig in ourselves instead of play guesses.

Comment: ok, I will do that

Comment: Would you mind using [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files? Files from other sources tend to "vanish" over thime thus possibly rendering your question and answers useless.

Comment: Like the vehicle!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded i tried your mesh. Number 1, if possible use a surface below the object. That way a lot more light bounces and illuminates it. Number 2, you might want to switch your "Color Mangement - View transform - to Filmic (instead of film". Its giving nice results over hear.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, but even with this enabled the lighting still looks very dim compared to the viewport

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the 2.8 beta?  I had the same issue. I updated Blender and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, a simple way is to use a brighter Background Color?
With brighter BG Colors the whole scene gets more background light.

[image: Background Color]

If you don't want the bright background, you can switch to transparent background to compose another background in it.

[image: Render transparent mode]

Answer (score -1):

Play with the *Exposure* and *Color Management* settings:

[image: play with these settings]

Comment: Hi. You need to make sure you don't have text on the same line as the image URL. It was messing up the formatting. Thanks.

Comment: hahaha sorry I'm new to this ;(  .. thanks for editing ;)